# mapping a grails action to a parent controller

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I would like to map some actions in a child class to their super class, but I cannot figure it out. Example below...

```
abstract class A {
    abstract def foo()

    def aAction1 = {
       // do something
       render(view: '/someView')
    }
    def aAction2 = { 
       SomeObject someObject ->
       // do something
       render(view: '/someView2')
    }
}

class B extents A {
    def foo() { return "Hello World" }

    # map to parent action    
    # works fine
    def jump = super.&aAction1
    # doesnt work ... Why? and can I make it work?
    def swim = { SomeObject someObject ->
       super.aAction2(someObject)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on this one? Thanks.

Comment: How doesn't it work? As an aside, unless you're redefining aAction1/2 in the child class, you don't need to specify super. You inherit the definitions.

Comment: I get instantiation exceptions.

Comment: Also, if I remove swim and allow it to fall into aAction2, I get an exception `java.lang.InstantiationException
 at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)`

Comment: So it turns out it didnt work because the parameters were slightly different. It does seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it didnt work because the parameters were slightly different. It does seem to work as expected. If you are having issues with this, make sure that the parameters for any inherited classes are exactly the same as the parent.